# Creating tuples of all possible combinations of items from two lists, without duplicating items within tuples

Tags: python, combinatorics

I would like to be able to take a range of numbers and return a list containing triples without duplicates.  Each element of x should appear once in each position of the triples.  The goal is to get something like the following:

```
get_combinations_without_duplicates(3) = [(0, 1, 2), (1, 2, 0), (2, 0, 1)]
```

For range(3) this is just a list rotation, but for higher ranges, there are more possible combinations.  I would like to be able to randomly generate a list of triples that satisfies these constraints.

Suppose we start by specifying the first element of each triple for the case where n=4:

[(0,), (1,), (2,), (3,)]

The second element of the first triple can be anything other than 0.  Once one of these is chosen, then this limits the options for the next triple, and so on.  The goal is to have a function that takes a number and creates the triples in this manner, but doesn't always create the same set of triples.  That is, the end result could be a rotation:

```
[(0, 1, 2), (1, 2, 3), (2, 3, 0), (3, 0, 1),]
```

or

```
[(0, 2, 3), (1, 3, 0), (2, 0, 1), (3, 1, 2)]
```

Here is an implementation of this function:

```
def get_combinations_without_duplicates(n):
    output = []
    second = range(n)
     third = range(n)
for i in range(n):
    triple = [i]
    #Get the second value of the triple, but make sure that it isn't a 
    #duplicate of the first value
    #in the triple or any value that has appeared in the second position of any triple
    choices_for_second = [number for number in second if number not in triple]
    #Randomly select a number from the allowed possibilities
    n_second = random.choice(choices_for_second) 
    #Append it to the triple
    triple.append(n_second)
    #Remove that value from second so that it won't be chosen for other triples
    second = [number for number in second if number != n_second]
    #Do the same for the third value
    choices_for_third = [number for number in third if number not in triple]
    n_third = random.choice(choices_for_third)
    triple.append(n_third)
    third = [number for number in third if number != n_third]
    output.append(tuple(triple))
return output
```

As pointed out below, this process will sometimes randomly select combinations that don't work.  That can be handled if you do something like:

```
def keep_trying(n):
    try:
        return get_combinations_without_duplicates(n)
    except IndexError:
        return keep_trying(n)
```

However, I'm wondering if there is a better way to do this in general.

Comment: What you're doing seems arbitrary. You say that each element of x should appear once in each position of the triples, but, in your example, there are two triples with zero in the first position: (0, 1, 2) and (0, 2, 1). How are you picking the one that you want to use?

Comment: Sorry, the triples in the list are (0, 1, 2), (1, 2, 0), and (2, 0, 1).  0 appears in the first position of the first triple, the second position of the second triple, and the third position of the third triple.

Comment: From what I understand it's every rotation of every possible subset of 3 numbers from the range. Right?

Comment: One thing which comes in very handy (he said, deleting his own solution) is for you to give a brute-force solution which gives the answers you want.  Then everyone can compare their interpretation of your words with the output of the code.

Comment: @wdnsd I added an actual solution procedure.

Answer (score 5):

Let's try this again.

A few observations.

1. The first value will always be zero in a sorted array of your tuples.
2. The length of the array will always be as long as the number of tuples that exist in your array.
3. You want these to be *randomly* generated.
4. The tuples are produced in 'sorted' order.

Based on these specifications, we can come up with a procedural method;

1. Generate 2 lists of serial integers, one to pick from, the other to seed from.
2. For each number in the seed list, `[0, 1, 2, 3]`, randomly append and remove a number that's not already in the element.  `[01, 13, 20, 32]`
3. Generate another list of serial integers, and repeat. `[012, 130, 203, 321]`

But, this doesn't work.  For some iterations, it will back itself into a corner and not be able to generate a number.  For instance, `[01, 13, 20, 32].. appending [3, 0, 1... crap, I'm stuck.`

The only way to fix this, is to do a *true* shuffling over the entire row, and reshuffle until one fits.  This may take quite a bit of time, and will only get more painful as the sets get longer.

So, procedurally speaking:

**Solution 1:** Random generation

1. Populate a list with your range.  [0, 1, 2, 3]
2. Create another list.  [0, 1, 2, 3]
3. Shuffle the list.  [1, 0, 2, 3]
4. Shuffle until you find one that fits... [1, 2, 3, 0]
5. Repeat with the third element.

With this procedure, while a computer can *verify* solutions very quickly, it cannot *generate* solutions very quickly.  However, it is merely one of two ways to generate a truly random answer.

Therefore, the fastest guaranteed method would use make use of a verification procedure, rather than a generating procedure.  First things first, generate all the possible permutations.

```
from itertools import permutations

n = 4
candidates = [i for i in permutations(xrange(n),3)]
```

Then.

**Solution 2:** Random verification

1. Pick a triplet that starts with 0.
2. Pop, at random, a triplet that does not start with 0.
3. Verify if the randomly picked triplet is an intermediate solution.
4. If not, pop another triplet.
5. If yes, append the triplet, and *REPOPULATE THE TRIPLET QUEUE*.
6. Repeat n times. # or until you exhaust the queue, at which point repeat n times naturally becomes TRUE

A solution for the next triplet is mathematically guaranteed to be in the solution set, so if you just let it exhaust itself, a randomized solution should appear.  The problem with this approach is that there's no guarantee that every *possible* outcome has an *equal* probability.

**Solution 3:** Iterative verification

For equal probability results, get rid of the randomization, and generate every possible 3-tuple combination, n-lists long-- and verify each of those solution candidates.

Write a function to *verify* over the list of candidate solutions to produce *every* solution, and then randomly pop a solution from that list.

```
from itertools import combinations

results = [verify(i) for i in combinations(candidates, n)]
# this is 10626 calls to verify for n=4, 5 million for n=5 
# this is not an acceptable solution.
```

Neither Solution 1 or 3 is very fast, O(n**2), but given your criteria, it's possible this is as fast as it'll get if you want a truly random solution.  Solution 2 will guaranteed be the fastest of these three, often times significantly beating 1 or 3, Solution 3 has the most stable results.  Which of these approaches you choose will depend on what you want to do with the output.

Afterward:

Ultimately, the speed of the code will be contingent on exactly *how random* you want your code to be.  An algorithm to spit out the VERY first (and only the very first) instance of a tuple series that satisfies your requirement can run supremely quickly, as it just attacks the permutations in order, once, and it will run in O(n) time.  However, it will not do anything randomly...

Also, here's some quick code for verify(i).  It's based on the observation that two tuples may not have the same number in the same index.

```
def verify(t):
    """ Verifies that a set of tuples satisfies the combinations without duplicates condition. """
    zipt = zip(*t)
    return all([len(i) == len(set(i)) for i in zipt])
```

n = 4 Full Solution Set

```
((0, 1, 2), (1, 0, 3), (2, 3, 0), (3, 2, 1))
((0, 1, 2), (1, 0, 3), (2, 3, 1), (3, 2, 0))
((0, 1, 2), (1, 2, 3), (2, 3, 0), (3, 0, 1))
((0, 1, 2), (1, 3, 0), (2, 0, 3), (3, 2, 1))
((0, 1, 3), (1, 0, 2), (2, 3, 0), (3, 2, 1))
((0, 1, 3), (1, 0, 2), (2, 3, 1), (3, 2, 0))
((0, 1, 3), (1, 2, 0), (2, 3, 1), (3, 0, 2))
((0, 1, 3), (1, 3, 2), (2, 0, 1), (3, 2, 0))
((0, 2, 1), (1, 0, 3), (2, 3, 0), (3, 1, 2))
((0, 2, 1), (1, 3, 0), (2, 0, 3), (3, 1, 2))
((0, 2, 1), (1, 3, 0), (2, 1, 3), (3, 0, 2))
((0, 2, 1), (1, 3, 2), (2, 0, 3), (3, 1, 0))
((0, 2, 3), (1, 0, 2), (2, 3, 1), (3, 1, 0))
((0, 2, 3), (1, 3, 0), (2, 0, 1), (3, 1, 2))
((0, 2, 3), (1, 3, 2), (2, 0, 1), (3, 1, 0))
((0, 2, 3), (1, 3, 2), (2, 1, 0), (3, 0, 1))
((0, 3, 1), (1, 0, 2), (2, 1, 3), (3, 2, 0))
((0, 3, 1), (1, 2, 0), (2, 0, 3), (3, 1, 2))
((0, 3, 1), (1, 2, 0), (2, 1, 3), (3, 0, 2))
((0, 3, 1), (1, 2, 3), (2, 1, 0), (3, 0, 2))
((0, 3, 2), (1, 0, 3), (2, 1, 0), (3, 2, 1))
((0, 3, 2), (1, 2, 0), (2, 1, 3), (3, 0, 1))
((0, 3, 2), (1, 2, 3), (2, 0, 1), (3, 1, 0))
((0, 3, 2), (1, 2, 3), (2, 1, 0), (3, 0, 1))
```

n = 5 has 552 unique solutions.  Here are the first 20.

```
((0, 1, 2), (1, 0, 3), (2, 3, 4), (3, 4, 0), (4, 2, 1))
((0, 1, 2), (1, 0, 3), (2, 3, 4), (3, 4, 1), (4, 2, 0))
((0, 1, 2), (1, 0, 3), (2, 4, 0), (3, 2, 4), (4, 3, 1))
((0, 1, 2), (1, 0, 3), (2, 4, 1), (3, 2, 4), (4, 3, 0))
((0, 1, 2), (1, 0, 4), (2, 3, 0), (3, 4, 1), (4, 2, 3))
((0, 1, 2), (1, 0, 4), (2, 3, 1), (3, 4, 0), (4, 2, 3))
((0, 1, 2), (1, 0, 4), (2, 4, 3), (3, 2, 0), (4, 3, 1))
((0, 1, 2), (1, 0, 4), (2, 4, 3), (3, 2, 1), (4, 3, 0))
((0, 1, 2), (1, 2, 0), (2, 3, 4), (3, 4, 1), (4, 0, 3))
((0, 1, 2), (1, 2, 0), (2, 4, 3), (3, 0, 4), (4, 3, 1))
((0, 1, 2), (1, 2, 3), (2, 0, 4), (3, 4, 0), (4, 3, 1))
((0, 1, 2), (1, 2, 3), (2, 0, 4), (3, 4, 1), (4, 3, 0))
((0, 1, 2), (1, 2, 3), (2, 3, 4), (3, 4, 0), (4, 0, 1))
((0, 1, 2), (1, 2, 3), (2, 4, 0), (3, 0, 4), (4, 3, 1))
((0, 1, 2), (1, 2, 3), (2, 4, 1), (3, 0, 4), (4, 3, 0))
((0, 1, 2), (1, 2, 4), (2, 0, 3), (3, 4, 0), (4, 3, 1))
((0, 1, 2), (1, 2, 4), (2, 0, 3), (3, 4, 1), (4, 3, 0))
((0, 1, 2), (1, 2, 4), (2, 3, 0), (3, 4, 1), (4, 0, 3))
((0, 1, 2), (1, 2, 4), (2, 3, 1), (3, 4, 0), (4, 0, 3))
((0, 1, 2), (1, 2, 4), (2, 4, 3), (3, 0, 1), (4, 3, 0))
```

So, you can generate solutions like this, but it takes time.  If you were going to utilize this, I would cache the solutions generated as is, and then randomly pull from them when you need them for whatever number n.  Incidentally, n=5 took a little under a minute to complete, brute force.  Since the solution is O(n**2), I expect n=6 to take over an hour, n=7 over a day.  The only way you can get return a true randomized solution is by doing it this way.

**Edited:** Random Solution without equal distribution:

The following is code I wrote in attempting to solve this problem, an implementation of **Solution 2**.  I figured I would post it, since it is a partial, non-equal distribution solution, and *generates every possible solution*, guaranteed, given enough time.

```
def seeder(n):
    """ Randomly generates the first element in a solution. """
    seed = [0]
    a = range(1, n)
    for i in range(1, 3):
        seed.append(a.pop(random.randint(0,len(a)-1)))
    return [seed]

def extend_seed(seed, n):
    """ Semi-Randomly generates the next element in a solution. """
    next_seed = [seed[-1][0] + 1]
    candidates = range(0, n)
    for i in range(1, 3):
        c = candidates[:]
        for s in next_seed:
            c.remove(s)
        for s in seed:
            try:
                c.remove(s[i])
            except ValueError:
                pass
        next_seed.append(c.pop(random.randint(0,len(c)-1)))
    seed.append(next_seed)
    return seed

def combo(n):
    """ Extends seed until exhausted. 
    Some random generations return results shorter than n. """
    seed = seeder(n)
    while True:
        try:
            extend_seed(seed, n)
        except (ValueError, IndexError):
            return seed

def combos(n):
    """ Ensures that the final return is of length n. """
    while True:
        result = combo(n)
        if len(result) == n:
            return result
```

Answer (score 2):

You essentially want a [Latin square](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Latin_square), a n x n grid of numbers where each row and each column contains each number exactly once, except you only care about the first three numbers in each row (a Latin rectangle).

**Update:**

I've erased my ineffective code sample, because generating random Latin squares with equal probability is non-trivial, as discussed [in a question on math.stackexchange.com](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/63131/generate-random-latin-squares).

The [SAGE project](http://www.sagemath.org/doc/reference/sage/combinat/matrices/latin.html#sage.combinat.matrices.latin.LatinSquare_generator) implements the algorithm mentioned in that question, so you may look at the code for inspiration.

Alternatively, if you really want to get into the details, check out [this paper](http://cs.anu.edu.au/~bdm/papers/randomlatin.pdf) for the specific case of generating random Latin rectangles.

Comment: Your solution doesn't produce `((0, 1, 2), (1, 0, 3), (2, 3, 0), (3, 2, 1))`, amongst other tuples.  Additionally, there is repetition, you end up with `[[0, 1, 2], [2, 3, 0], [1, 2, 3], [3, 0, 1]]` and `[[0, 1, 2], [2, 3, 0], [3, 0, 1], [1, 2, 3]]`, which switch the last two tuples.  Every generated set is a valid set, but the randomization is not working.

Comment: Thanks @kreativitea, you're correct -- the symbols must be permuted to generate all possible combinations.  The updated code should fix this.

Comment: It's still missing six solutions-- `[[0, 1, 2], [1, 0, 3], [2, 3, 0], [3, 2, 1]]
[[0, 1, 3], [1, 0, 2], [2, 3, 1], [3, 2, 0]]
[[0, 2, 1], [1, 3, 0], [2, 0, 3], [3, 1, 2]]
[[0, 2, 3], [1, 3, 2], [2, 0, 1], [3, 1, 0]]
[[0, 3, 1], [1, 2, 0], [2, 1, 3], [3, 0, 2]]
[[0, 3, 2], [1, 2, 3], [2, 1, 0], [3, 0, 1]]` # tested against my bruteforce result

Answer (score 1):

Actually itertools has solved this for you already.

```
import itertools

allp = [x for x in itertools.permutations(range(3))]
print allp

mylist = ['A','B','C']
allp2 = [x for x in itertools.permutations(mylist)]
print allp2
```

output

```
[(0, 1, 2), (0, 2, 1), (1, 0, 2), (1, 2, 0), (2, 0, 1), (2, 1, 0)]
[('A', 'B', 'C'), ('A', 'C', 'B'), ('B', 'A', 'C'), ('B', 'C', 'A'), ('C', 'A', 'B'), ('C', 'B', 'A')]
```

Comment: Pretty sure the OP wants 3-tuples for all lengths of `mylist`

Comment: you can do `list(itertools.permutations(range(3)))`

Answer (score 0):

Just a different viewpoint to your problem. See if this works for you

```
>>> from itertools import chain,combinations
>>> def get_combinations_without_duplicates(iterable):
        return (tuple(chain(*(set(iterable) - set(e) , e))) for e in combinations(iterable,2))

>>> list(get_combinations_without_duplicates(range(3)))
[(2, 0, 1), (1, 0, 2), (0, 1, 2)]
```

Comment: Fails for `list(get_combinations_without_duplicates(range(4)))` - `(1, 3, 0, 2)` and `(1, 2, 0, 3)` both have a `1` in the first position.

Comment: Not to mention they're not 3-tuples,, they're 4-tuples-- the OP specifically wants 3-tuples.  @Abhijit

Comment: @kreativitea: I have no idea how I missed that.

Answer (score 0):

A simple list rotation provides a correct solution for all n >= 3:

Consider the rotation solution for n = 5:

```
[
    (0, 1, 2),
    (1, 2, 3),
    (2, 3, 4),
    (3, 4, 0),
    (4, 0, 1)
]
```

Each number appears in each position only once, and for each position all numbers are present.

---

In general, `len(get_combinations_without_duplicates(n)) == n` for n >= 3

Answer (score 0):

here is an approach that takes advantage of deque.rotate

```
>>> datax = []
>>> from collections import deque
>>> data_length = 10
>>> subset_length = 3
>>> for i in xrange(0, subset_length):
...     datax.append(deque(xrange(data_length)))
...
>>> for i in xrange(0, subset_length):
...     datax[i].rotate(i)
...
>>> print zip(*datax)
[(0, 9, 8), (1, 0, 9), (2, 1, 0), (3, 2, 1), (4, 3, 2), (5, 4, 3), (6, 5, 4), (7, 6, 5), (8, 7, 6), (9, 8, 7)]
```

Comment: This is just a variation on the rotation solution, and does not produce a random solution.